# bzr: change saved location

Tags: bazaar

How can I change the saved location of repository when using bzr ?

When you do: `bzr push`, it's normally what you can see:

`Using saved push location: bzr+ssh://bazaar.launchpad.net/XX`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use option `--remember` to remember the specified location on push.

```
bzr push --remember [LOCATION]
```

If no location was defined yet a "specified location" will be created on first run.

<sup>source [BZR User Reference](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/user-reference/push-help.html)</sup>